Why use ReturnType here?
I was learning how remeda types their reverse function and saw this
type Reverse<
  T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>,
  R extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> = [],
> = ReturnType< // <------------------ Why ReturnType here ?
  T extends IsNoTuple<T>
    ? () => [...T, ...R]
    : T extends readonly [infer F, ...infer L]
      ? () => Reverse<L, [F, ...R]>
      : () => R
>;

I know a few typescript "hacks" to get typescript to behave in a way that isn't yet configurable - but I'm unfamiliar with this one, and know it's not specific to remeda hence this question.  An explanation also wasn't in the commit which introduced this code.
To be clear, I'd expect the type to be written this way
type Reverse<
  T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>,
  R extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> = []
> =
  T extends IsNoTuple<T>
    ? [...T, ...R]
    : T extends readonly [infer F, ...infer L]
      ? Reverse<L, [F, ...R]>
      : R


It's hard to know why someone wrote something a particular way without asking them. If I were writing Reverse I'd write it as type Reverse<T, A extends any[] = []> = T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? Reverse<R, [F, ...A]> : A until and unless there were use cases that necessitated something more complicated. Without a description of use cases, all we can do is guess. How would you know if someone answered this correctly? Maybe there's some way to [edit] the question to rephrase it so it has a possibly objective non-guess answer? Otherwise it seems too subjective or ill-posed for SO.

@jcalz I agree in general, questions of authored code are best asked to the author.  I specifically didn't post an issue in their repo because  I'm pretty sure I've seen this when browsing typescript code in the past - I figured this was a general typescript hack used a lot of places.  If you're unfamilliar with it though then I will post in their repo and report back here.  I disagree the question as-asked is subjective.  I think there is clearly typescript behavior that is being manipulated here, I'm just unable to prescribe what.

I’m voting to close this question because it can't be answered

If I had to guess, I would say the author is attempting to manage the infinite recursion issues.

Per the author - he doesn't remember

can’t remember why I went for functions and return types here  . Chances are I didn’t really know what I was doing in 2020.

And a current maintainer of remeda isn't familiar with why the code would be written that way.

This code predates my time working on the library. If you have an issue caused by this you can share more info on that and I'll try to help, otherwise, if you are just curious you can try to ping the pr #95 to ask the author directly.

I'll close the question and if I come across this type of code again I'll ask the author directly.

It's a Utility type built into TypeScript, you can read about it (and the other utility types) here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype
Sometimes if a type is unclear, complex, etc it's easier to just tell typescript "use the return type from this.
A simple example where I use this a lot is when I need to save a setTimeout for a debounce operation
private counter?: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;

If you don't sometimes it will say the type is NodeJS.Timeout and sometimes it might say it's from the non-Node definitions. I don't care and I don't want to fight the type system or provide a differen type in a front end vs. back end project, so I just use ReturnType

This doesn't seem to address the question as asked. The question isn't "why might one use ReturnType, it's "why are they using it here"? They are taking a type like X, making a function from it () => X, and then getting its return type ReturnType<() => X>. Why the indirection? Why not just use X rather than take the detour?

Right.  To give an example of a typescript hack, is to append ... extends infer O ? O : never which will always pass O.  In my case this allowed me to display a type alias instead of the expanded type in intellisense.  I figured using ReturnType here was similarly modifying typescript behavior but it turns out the code could just be unnecessary
